# How to connect PHP with HIVE?

Tags: php, hive

I want to make a website where I'll be using big data at back end . I'm using hadoop framework and I wish to store the data in HDFS and want to fetch it using HIVE and display it in the browser.
 I do know how to fetch and display data using PHP+MySQL.
 Now the problem is I don't know how to use PHP with HIVE to do the job.
 I'll be thankful to you if you kindly explain it from the scratch.
:)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This site is for questions. You show what you tried and researched and report on what you got stuck on then we try to help.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the ODBC connectors available for Hive.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveODBC
http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php

Hive also has a Thrift interface which is more faster.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveClient#HiveClient-Thrift
https://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/php